# Create a buffer and pipe data to play it javascript

Tags: javascript, audio, electron, webtorrent

I'm trying to play streaming sound from torrent using electron. To do this I'm using https://github.com/feross/webtorrent to download all the data in the main proccess of electron. Then when I select a sound to download I get a stream of the file to play and send to html renderer proccess in the follow function

```
ipc.on('getPlayData', function(event, data){
    console.log('get file data stream');
    in_play = data[1];

    //Crea el stream del archivo que se va a reproducir
    var streamfile = downloaderInstance.getFileToPlay(data[0], data[1]).createReadStream();

    //se envia la longiud del archivo en bytes para el buffer.
    event.sender.send('toPlay', [downloaderInstance.getFileToPlay(data[0], data[1]).name,
             downloaderInstance.getFileToPlay(data[0], data[1]).length]);

    streamfile.on('data', function(chunk){
        event.sender.send('addData', chunk);
});
```

where 'toPlay' message tell the renderer parameters of the file that need to put in html and data send every data that I get from the seeders of torrent.

Then in the renderer procces I get the data into a buffer to use it with https://github.com/feross/render-media but I also try to work with WebAudioApi of javascript. I manage the data in the follow function:

```
ipc.on('toPlay', (event, data) => {
    console.log("to play: " + data[0]);
    var buf = [];
    var stream_length = parseInt(data[1]);
    var stream_data = Buffer.alloc(stream_length);

    ipc.on('addData', (event, data) => {
         buf.push(data);
         stream_data = Buffer.concat(buf);
    })

    var file = {
         name: data[0],
         createReadStream: function(opts){
         //console.log(stream_data.length);
         return from( [stream_data.slice(0, stream_length) ]);
         }
    }

    //console.log(file.createReadStream);
    render.render(file, 'audio', [true, true, stream_length], function(err, elem){
     if(err){ return console.log('error appending') }
    })
})
```

where render it's a function that play the media source in the audio DOM node. My problem it's it's that I reserve the fully memory of the file in the buffer, set the render function the fully duration of file but it only play the data that I already downloaded and not reload the data when news are received by ipc and I can't find a way to do this.

Comment: You can use `<progress>` and `buffered` property of Audio Object.

Comment: Can you give me some link or example please. @JuanjoSalvador

Comment: This may helps you http://www.inserthtml.com/2013/03/custom-html5-video-player/

Answer (score 1):

The solution is

```
var readableStream = new Readable();

var file = {
         name: data[0],
         createReadStream: function(opts){
         return ReadableStream;
         }
    }
```

but the readable should be fully loaded before the return.

Comment: Looks promising I'm going to try it out now